# Rewrite url in wordpress for additional php files

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created php file in theme.
So for that page I am getting url as:

```
.../site-name/wp-content/themes/mytheme/admin-dashboard.php
```

I want it as

```
../site-name/admin-dashboard
```

So how to do it?Using htaccess or is there any other way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create a new wp page, name it admin-dashboard
2. create a shortcode for admin-dashboard.php content and add it to admin-dashboard wp page